# How can I get a input in this code

Tags: python

So I am creating a game, and when the player has won, it will end up in a highscore list - a txt file at my desktop in this case. And i'm not sure that how or where I should put this code (and how do i connect that to my .txt file???)

---

**EDIT:** I see now that my whole text didn't come with, i meant that i want to have an input so the player can write his nickname/name etc, så that name end up in the .txt file. but I'm not sure where in the code i will use input, and how to write it so it will connect?

---

Here's a little bit of my code:

```
if sum(map(lambda row: row.count(' '), currutnat)) == antal_minor: # spelet klart, (räkna alla minor == antalet  utsatt)
            totaltid = int(time.time() - starttid) # hur lång tid tog det här spelet
            scores = []
            fil = open("melinas.txt", "r+") # läs in "gamla" highscores
            while 1:
                line = fil.readline()
                if not line:
                    break
                scores.append(int(line))

            # Lägg in hur lång tid det här tog
            scores.append(totaltid)
            # Sortera highscores
            scores.sort()
            if (len(scores) > 10): # om fler än 10 spel, "klipp" listan till 10 värden
                scores = scores[:10]
            print(scores)
            fil.seek(0) #SKriver de nya siffrorna överst i filen

            # skriv highscores med ny rad
            fil.write("\n".join(str(x) for x in scores))
            fil.truncate()
            fil.close()
            ##### Ta bort när det funkar och kopiera till när man vunnit längre ner

            minutes, seconds = divmod(totaltid, 60)

            print(
                'You won:) '
                'it took u{} minutes & {} sek.\n'.format(minutes,
                                                                  seconds))
```

Comment: Please correct your indentation.

Comment: I'm seriously skeptical that **you** are creating a game (or wrote the above code) if you're asking that question. Your question is too broad, anyway - try asking for help with a specific problem.

Comment: Shall I in future take with me the whole code? it some many lines?

Answer (score 0):

Put this file in the same folder as the .txt file. If the .txt file is on your Desktop, you should also put the code file on your Desktop.

Desktop: mycode.py, melina.txt

Another option is to change your path to and *absolute* path. Then your code can be anywhere. If your text file is on your Desktop, you would change the line that opens the file to this:

```
fil = open("~/Desktop/melinas.txt", "r+") # läs in "gamla" highscores
```

The way I wrote it does assume you are on a linux computer.

Comment: omg, i see now that my whole text didn't come with, i meant that i want to have an input so the player can write his nickname/name etc, så that name end up in the .txt file. 

but I'm not sure where in the code i will use input, and how to write it so i will connect?

Comment: Try something like: name = input("What is your name?") and then use the string you get back?

Comment: Yes. but where in the code? when the game is finished or in the highscorE?